# SQL Server : Regular Expression in Like

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-like

I'm having trouble getting a regular expression to work in SQL Server.

I take in a comma separated list, each item a string I will want to match against.

```
DECLARE @List TABLE ([SearchText] VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO @List ([SearchText])
SELECT CAST(Item AS VARCHAR)
FROM dbo.fnSplit(@IDs, ',')

UPDATE @List SET  SearchText = '%controller/action/' + SearchText + '%'
```

then I need to find if this match is in certain tables.

```
SELECT ID FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN @List L ON t1.[Url] LIKE L.SearchText
```

the problem is this would match 'controller/action/283' and 'controller/action/2834'

So I tried `'%controller/action/' + SearchText + '[^0-9]%'` and this almost works. It works on 'controller/action/2834' but it doesn't match against 'controller/action/283' when there's nothing after it. The problem I'm currently having is normal regular expression don't seem to be working in this syntax as I cant just do `'(\b|[^0-9])%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify both possibilities, combined by 'OR':

```
UPDATE @List SET SearchText = '%controller/action/' + SearchText

SELECT ID FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN @List L ON t1.[Url] LIKE L.SearchText
                   OR t1.[Url] LIKE L.SearchText + '[^0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the wildcards in the update:

```
UPDATE @List SET  SearchText = 'controller/action/' + SearchText
```

Change the select to:

```
SELECT ID FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN @List L ON t1.[Url] LIKE '%' + L.SearchText + '%'
```

The wildcard(s) need to be applied when you are selecting the data, not when you are storing it.